# Matplotlib, Inkscape, Spyder, plots and SVG compatibility (true axis size)

Tags: matplotlib, svg, plot, axis, inkscape

I have been plotting data for years during my PhD and always had to fight with something that unfortunately plagues the scientific community: negligent data manipulation.

My problem is that when I plot with matplotlib two graphics with different number lengths in the Y axis, the result is two graphics with two different X axis sizes.
When I copy the resulting SVG image directly from Spyder IPython console (Copy SVG) and paste in Inkscape for editing, matching the axis is a painful task which requires scaling them correctly with absolute precision. I am aware there plugins that are able to rescale plots in Inkscape and etc.

Comment: Journals and websites don't care how large you axes are, but rather how wide your figures are.

Comment: This is not related to what journals and websites care about or not. It is regarding image manipulation of vector graphics; to be able to stitch together two or more graphics in inkscape, made with matplotlib. The figure size is something that can be easily configured later in inkscape.

Answer (score 0):

Bonus solved problem 1: for some reason, the size of an SVG created by matplotlib is scaled by 0.75 relative to Inkscape

Bonus solved problem 2: Matplotlib uses... inches, so the 25.4 that is in the following code lines is simply to convert from inch to millimeters.

Sometimes, having more control at the root is better than patching and patching and patching. So here is my solution to those who have been agonizing like me over being able to have two plots with the same absolute axis sizes:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

inch = False # Set to True if you want to use inch (blergh...).

width  = 50 # The actual size in millimeters for the X axis to have.
height = 20 # The actual size in millimeters for the Y axis to have.

figsize = [(-0.212+width)/(1+24.4*(not inch)),(-0.212+height)/(1+24.4*(not inch))] # [W, H]

# Attention to the 0.212 mm which is thickness of the axis line; the cap at the end of the axis is half of thickness and is accounted for the size of the axis in Inkscape. So, when you use the size of a line from Inkscape as the desired size of the axis in a plot from matplotlib, ax.get_linewidth() by default should be 0.8 (whatever 0.8 is.. but it seems like 0.212/25.4 * 100).

height_scale = 3 # Scale to account for the axis title, labels and ticks.
width_scale = 2  # Scale to account for the axis title, labels and ticks.

figsize = [width_scale*figsize[0]/0.75, height_scale*figsize[1]/0.75] 

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (figsize[0], figsize[1]))

wpos   = (50/(1+24.4*(not inch)))/(figsize[0]/0.75) # Giving 50 mm mandatory position shift for the Y axis, to accommodate the title, labels and ticks.
hpos   = (40/(1+24.4*(not inch)))/(figsize[1]/0.75) # Giving 40 mm mandatory position shift for the X axis to accommodate the  title, labels and ticks.

# Now comes the problem. The AXIS size is defined relatively to the FIGURE size. The following values will simply use the rescaled FIGURE sizes:

wscale = 1/width_scale  # = (width_scale*figsize[0]/0.75)/width_scale = figsize[0]/0.75 which is our target size for Inkscape.
hscale = 1/height_scale 

ax = fig.add_axes([wpos, hpos, wscale, hscale])
```

Then you can plot at will, copy the SVG output (in Spyder's IPython console, at least) and paste it in Inkscape.

The only set back is that the whole FIGURE size will be abnormal and you'll have to remove the white background from it in Inkscape. But that is something probably all of us already do.

This is a minimal working code. You can paste it in your IPython console and copy the SVG output, paste it in Inkscape and check the axis line size. It will be with a width of 50 mm and a height of 20 mm.